# Horizontal scrollbars on responsive site after change in orientation

Tags: responsive-design

I'm not going to paste a mass of code here, since I don't expect anyone to go through it line by line to find what my problem is.

Basically, when I change the device from portrait to landscape orientation, then BACK to portrait, there's horizontal scrollbars and the content can be moved around, which is not cool.

I have the usual `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />`.
Anyone got any clue what gives rise to this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is the problem in device's orientation from portrait to landscape or vice-versa. Just try to use the following.

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen mostly when the keyboard is up?

If yes, try this : https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix